Dystopian story in which people are killed randomly even if they are "reformed" into accepting the regime
One day I was browsing the questions/answers of Sci-Fi Stack Exchange, and I think I came across a question which asked why the protagonists of the story, after getting brainwashed, still got picked up by the regime to be randomly executed, despite having been brainwashed into accepting it.
I think one of the answers was pointing out the reason was because even though they were reformed into conforming like everyone else, the whole system was still depicted as been an unfair one, and no matter how properly you were fitting into the criteria of a good citizen, you could still be chosen for random execution.
I'm almost certain this was something I read on this site some time between 2020 and 2024. I initially thought this was 1984 but after having a quick look at the existing questions/answers and the plot on Wikipedia, I was not able to find the story I remembered. Perhaps I'm mistaking it with another similar story.

The ending of 1984 perfectly fits your description. Our hero now loves Big Brother, but is warned that he'll eventually get picked up and killed just because.

@Valorum Perhaps I misunderstood the answer then. I thought there was, like, a monthly lottery during which random citizens would be chosen to be eliminated, independently of whether they've always been good citizens™, "reformed" citizens, or dissident ones.

Since you mention a lottery, could you rule out the other obvious answer, The Lottery? There don't appear to be any answers for that story, but it was mentioned in a comment for another book titled "the lottery".

@qazmlpok - The Lottery doesn't really fit the question. There isn't really a regime to accept or not accept, or talk of rebellion or brainwashing  - it's a short story though, so it might actually be quicker to just read it than to search for answers confirming whether it's the one!
